# ¿Cómo aceptar un valor null en C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Tengo un método que registra un usuario pero tengo un campo fechaFin de tipo `string` que cuando el valor recibe ***null*** se pasa al catch y quisiera saber como hacer para que acepte null.

En sql server ya esta validado para que acepte @FECHA_FIN = NULL

```
    public string InsertarMantUsuario(Usuario usu)
    {
        string resultadoInsertar = "";

        DatabaseHelper helper = null;
        try
        {
            helper = new DatabaseHelper(Conexion.Instancia.CadenaConexionDS());
            helper.BeginTransaction();

            helper.AddParameter("@USUARIO", usu.User);
            helper.AddParameter("@CLAVE", usu.Password);
            helper.AddParameter("@NOMBRE", usu.persona.Nombre);
            helper.AddParameter("@APELLIDO_PATERNO", usu.persona.ApPaterno);
            helper.AddParameter("@APELLIDO_MATERNO", usu.persona.ApMaterno);
            helper.AddParameter("@CORREO", usu.Correo);
            helper.AddParameter("@FECHA_INICIO", usu.fechaInicio.ToString());
            helper.AddParameter("@FECHA_FIN", string.IsNullOrEmpty(usu.fechaFin.ToString())?DBNull.Value`introducir el código aquí`:(object)usu.fechaFin.ToString());
            helper.AddParameter("@ID_PERFIL", usu.perfil.idPerfil);

            resultadoInsertar = Convert.ToString(helper.ExecuteScalar("PA_USUARIO_MANTENIMIENTO_I", CommandType.StoredProcedure, BinaryIntellect.DataAccess.ConnectionState.KeepOpen));

            helper.CommitTransaction();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            helper.RollbackTransaction();
            resultadoInsertar = "";
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (helper != null)
                helper.Dispose();
        }
        return resultadoInsertar;
    }
```

El error me muestra lo siguiente

```
{"Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto."}
Usuario.FechaFin.get Returned null
System.NullReferenceException
```

Comment: que error tira?

Comment: Te debe de dar algun error puesto que si fechaFin es NULL, no podrias ejecutar usu.fechaFin.ToString()

Comment: FechaInicio si te acepta nulos, verdad? El error ese ese que te comentaba, si fechaFin es nulo, no puedes ejecutar fechaFin.ToString(), ese es el metodo que da error puesto que fechafin es nulo y no encuentra el metodo ToString(). Dejandolo como tienes fechaInicio , estaría bien. Si es NULL, se pondra NULL, y si es otro valor se pondra otro valor. O cambiar tu validacion por  string.IsNullOrEmpty(usu.fechaFin)?DBNull.Value`introducir el código aquí`:(object)usu.fechaFin);

Comment: Creo que el error es string.IsNullOrEmpty(usu.fechaFin.ToString()), tendria que ser string.IsNullOrEmpty(usu.fechaFin) y si es un Datetime declaralo como nulleable asi datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente deja :

```
helper.AddParameter("@FECHA_FIN", string.IsNullOrEmpty(usu.fechaFin)?DBNull.Value`introducir el código aquí`:(object)usu.fechaFin);
```

o :

```
helper.AddParameter("@FECHA_FIN", usu.fechaFin);
```

Comment: Gracias @Alexmaister

Comment: De nada @Dum para eso estamos, ayudar y aprender.

Comment: Comprendes porque fallaba?

Comment: toString() estaba convirtiendo  a cadena un valor que es nulo y por ello votaba el error.

Comment: No exactamente. fechaFin es null, por lo que no contiene nada, ni valor ni metodos asociados. es decir dentro de fechaFin no existe el metodo toString(), hasta que se le asigne un objeto de tipo string

Answer (score 0):

me da que el fallo está aquí:

```
helper.AddParameter("@FECHA_FIN", string.IsNullOrEmpty(usu.fechaFin.ToString())?DBNull.Value`introducir el código aquí`:(object)usu.fechaFin.ToString());
```

sustituye lo anterior por

```
helper.AddParameter("@FECHA_FIN", string.IsNullOrEmpty(usu.fechaFin.ToString())?DBNull.Value:(object)usu.fechaFin.ToString());
```

Comment: usu.fechaFin.ToString() seguiria dando un NULL POINTER EXCEPTION

Comment: Si me sigue mostrando error

Comment: @Dum ¿el mismo error?  o es otro, especifica por favor.

Comment: si usu.fechaFin es de tipo string por qué haces .ToString()?